# Can't install powershell in Parallels Kali Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: powershell, virtual, parallels, locked-files

I've been trying to install Powershell for a few hours now. I run this under root:

```
apt update && apt -y install powershell
```

This is what I end up getting after it runs through and seemingly downloads

```
Package powershell is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'powershell' has no installation candidate
```

When I try to run this same command outside of root using sudo, I get the following:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I have updated everything and tried a few different ways. I even downloaded a completely new Virtual Machine in Parallels to see if restarting would help out. I still run into the same problems. This is a Kali Linux VM on Parallels MacOS M1. Not sure if that matters or not. I think Parallels itself may possibly be using an apt process in the background, but when I do:

```
sudo killall apt apt-get
```

I end up getting

```
apt: no process found
apt-get: no process found
```

I've been trying everything. I'm on a new Mac so I don't have too many VM options. If someone could figure this out in Parallels, it would be a great help.

I've tried a lot. In the description above.

Comment: There is a whole documentation on steps you can follow for macOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.2 hope that helps

Comment: I may have misread the question, so for Kali you can follow Debian's doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-debian?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

To install PowerShell in Kali Linux open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y snapd # install daemon and tooling that enable snap packages
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd apparmor
```

Log out and back in again, and run the following command to install the powershell snap package.

```
sudo snap install powershell --classic
```